# Explanation of why poles in the S-matrix corresponding to particle production/bound states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I've frequently heard the statement that the only singularities of the S-matrix in QFT correspond to things like the existence of bound states and the possibility of multi-particle production. I'm certain I've seen this worked out before, but for some reason I can't find any place that explicitly shows how these singularities arise in the S-matrix for these cases. Can someone point me to a reference for this, or explain why this is the case?

Comment: Weinberg's textbook *The Quantum Theory of Fields* Volume 1, section 10.2 "Polology" has a great discussion of this.